# How to change unit increment in hazard ratio from coxph and frailty model in R?

Tags: r

I ran a `coxph` model and a frailty model, but now I would like to change the hazard ratio for continuous variable (age) to show in terms of 5-unit increment instead of 1-unit.  Is there a function in R that can perform such task? If so, does the function also work for frailty mode? I used the package `frailtypack`.

```
library('survival')
data(veteran)

cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age, data = veteran)
summary(cox)

# Call:
#   coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ age, data = veteran)
# 
#   n= 137, number of events= 128 
# 
#         coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)
# age 0.007500  1.007528 0.009565 0.784    0.433
# 
#     exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
# age     1.008     0.9925    0.9888     1.027
# 
# Concordance= 0.515  (se = 0.029 )
# Likelihood ratio test= 0.63  on 1 df,   p=0.4
# Wald test            = 0.61  on 1 df,   p=0.4
# Score (logrank) test = 0.62  on 1 df,   p=0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new variable that represents the age group each subject belongs to; for example 1: 0-4, 2: 5-9, 3: 10-15, etc.

This is an example using the `veteran` dataset in the `survival` package. The data has a continuous variable `age`. Adding this as a predictor to the model will give you the relative risk (hazard ratio) for a one-year increase or increment in age. If you are interested in the x-year increment, you should generate a new variable which groups subjects accordingly. For these data, I applied the following grouping; group 1: `younger than 40`, group 2: `40 - <50`, group 3: `50 - < 60`, group 4: `60 - <70`, and group 5: `70 or older`. As such, the HR for a 10-year increment is 1.049. Alternatively, the risk increases with 5% for every 10 year increase in age. Note that the association is not statistically significant.

```
library(survival)
data(veteran)

veteran$ageCat <- 5
veteran$ageCat[veteran$age < 70] <- 4
veteran$ageCat[veteran$age < 60] <- 3
veteran$ageCat[veteran$age < 50] <- 2
veteran$ageCat[veteran$age < 40] <- 1

table(veteran$ageCat)

 1  2  3  4  5 
11 20 22 72 12 

cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ ageCat, data = veteran)
summary(cox)


Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ ageCat, data = veteran)

  n= 137, number of events= 128 

          coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)
ageCat 0.04793   1.04910  0.09265 0.517    0.605

       exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
ageCat     1.049     0.9532    0.8749     1.258

Concordance= 0.509  (se = 0.028 )
Rsquare= 0.002   (max possible= 0.999 )
Likelihood ratio test= 0.27  on 1 df,   p=0.6024
Wald test            = 0.27  on 1 df,   p=0.6049
Score (logrank) test = 0.27  on 1 df,   p=0.6048
```

Answer (score 0):

@milan's post answers a similar question but not the one as asked. Since age was split into decades and modeled as a continuous variable, the hazard ratio would compare a subject's age-decade compared to the next youngest decade. That is, the HR for subjects aged 51 vs 49 or 59 vs 41 would be the same despite 2 or 18 years between them.

Anyway, the default as you suggest is for a 1-unit increment in the continuous variable, age in this case. It's not always useful to compare subjects by 1-unit change especially when the range gets to be much larger.

You can do the following which is naive to the model, so this should would for a `lm`, `glm`, `survival::coxph`, `frailtypack::frailtyPenal`, etc.

```
library('survival')
data(veteran)

## 1-year increase in age
cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age, data = veteran)
exp(coef(cox))
#      age
# 1.007528
```

For a multiplicative model like Cox regressions, you can get the x-unit change after the model is fit:

```
## 5-year increase in age
exp(coef(cox)) ^ 5
#      age
# 1.038211

## or equivalently
exp(coef(cox) * 5)
#      age
# 1.038211
```

However, it's easier to create a variable for the age transformation then fit the model:

```
## or you can create a variable to model
veteran <- within(veteran, {
  age5 <- age / 5
})
cox5_1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age5, data = veteran)
exp(coef(cox5_1))
#    age10
# 1.038211

cox5_2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ I(age / 5), data = veteran)
exp(coef(cox5_2))
# I(age/5)
# 1.038211
```

Note you need to use `I` here in the formula interface since some operators have special meanings in formulae. For example, `lm(mpg ~ wt - 1, mtcars)` and `lm(mpg ~ I(wt - 1), mtcars)` are two different models.

You can use these methods in other models, for example `frailtyPenal` if that is indeed the one you are using:

```
library('frailtypack')
fp <- frailtyPenal(Surv(time, status) ~ age, data = veteran, n.knots = 12, kappa = 1e5)
exp(fp$coef)
exp(fp$coef) ^ 5

fp5_1 <- frailtyPenal(Surv(time, status) ~ age5, data = veteran, n.knots = 12, kappa = 1e5)
fp5_2 <- frailtyPenal(Surv(time, status) ~ I(age / 5), data = veteran, n.knots = 12, kappa = 1e5)
exp(fp5_1$coef)
exp(fp5_2$coef)
```